# Wordpress page slug with other content appended

Tags: wordpress

I want to get this result.
I created a page with slug "book" but I want to reach this page even using other content appended to url and not just http://mywebsite/book (just to improve SEO).
Example http://mywebsite/book/good-description...

Is It possible?

Comment: What exactly do you need? What is the good-description, Is that title or Content ? Create a post type instead

Comment: @SudharshanNair I want to go into the page http://mywebsite/book (slug book) even if I write http://mywebsite/book/abc/xyx or http://mywebsite/book/bye/hello.
The content after "book" is dynamically created

Comment: use the plugin I have suggested

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
        add_rewrite_rule('^(index.php/)?book/([^/]*)/?','index.php?pagename=book&book_model=$matches[2]','top');